# How to deserialize specialized floating values with GSON to Double when type is Object

Tags: java, gson

I have a class that has an Object[] field to store values and I need to be able to deserialize it with gson such that specialized floating point values are Double and not String.

Here is some test code.  The second assert fails, because the special values are deserialized as Strings:

```
@Test
public void testGson() {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeSpecialFloatingPointValues().create();
    ValuesObject toJson = new ValuesObject(0, new Object[] { 0.0, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, Double.NaN });

    String json = gson.toJson(toJson);
    assertEquals("{\"type\":0,\"values\":[0.0,Infinity,-Infinity,NaN]}", json);

    ValuesObject fromJson = gson.fromJson(json, ValuesObject.class);
    assertEquals(toJson, fromJson); // fails
}

private class ValuesObject {
    private int type;
    private Object[] values;

    public ValuesObject(int type, Object[] values) {
        this.type = type;
        this.values = values;
    }

    // snip... equals and hashCode
}
```

I know that the answer lies in a custom TypeAdapter or Deserializer, but I don't see the best approach.  All I really want to do is override ObjectTypeAdapter to handle these three special case String values, but the code is not extendable.  It seems that an entire adapter needs to be implemented.

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/64949367/844123, I have something that works, but is it the best way to do it?

```
class ValuesObjectTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    private ValuesObjectTypeAdapterFactory() { }

    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
        if (type.getRawType() != Object[].class) {
            return null;
        }

        // Get the default adapter as delegate
        // Cast is safe due to `type` check at method start
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        TypeAdapter<Object> delegate = (TypeAdapter<Object>) gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
        // Cast is safe because `T` is ValuesObject or subclass (due to `type` check at method start)

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        TypeAdapter<T> adapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) new TypeAdapter<>() {
            @Override
            public void write(JsonWriter out, Object value) throws IOException {
                delegate.write(out, value);
            }

            @Override
            public Object read(JsonReader in) {
                JsonElement jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(in);

                Object value = delegate.fromJsonTree(jsonObject);
                if (value instanceof Object[]) {
                    Object[] array = (Object[]) value;
                    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
                        if (array[i] instanceof String) {
                            switch ((String)array[i]) {
                                case "Infinity":
                                case "-Infinity":
                                case "NaN":
                                    array[i] = Double.valueOf((String) array[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return value;
            }
        };

        return adapter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case only that specific field should be deserialized in this way, you can use [`@JsonAdapter`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.html) on that field instead of registering the type adapter factory globally with a `GsonBuilder` to avoid affecting other unrelated fields. You then need to replace the call to `gson.getDelegateAdapter` with `gson.getAdapter` due to [this Gson issue](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1028).

You should avoid using `JsonParser` here; it always parses the JSON in lenient mode regardless of the `JsonReader` setting (though it does not matter much here because you have to use lenient mode anyways to parse the non-finite numbers). Unfortunately that is currently not well documented. Instead you can use `gson.getAdapter(JsonElement.class)` and use the returned adapter to parse the JSON. However, for your use case it is not even needed to parse the JSON as `JsonElement`, you can instead directly call `delegate.read(in)`.

The following shows the recommended changes. It uses "diff-like" formatting where every line starting with `-` should be removed, and every line starting with `+` should be added:

```java
+/**
+ * Should only be used with Gson's {@link JsonAdapter}; otherwise infinite recursion can occur.
+ */
 class ValuesObjectTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
 
-    private ValuesObjectTypeAdapterFactory() { }
+    // Default constructor for Gson's @JsonAdapter
+    public ValuesObjectTypeAdapterFactory() { }
 
     @Override
     public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
         if (type.getRawType() != Object[].class) {
             return null;
         }
 
         // Get the default adapter as delegate
         // Cast is safe due to `type` check at method start
         @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
-        TypeAdapter<Object> delegate = (TypeAdapter<Object>) gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
+        // Uses `getAdapter` as workaround for https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1028
+        TypeAdapter<Object> delegate = (TypeAdapter<Object>) gson.getAdapter(type);
 
         @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
         TypeAdapter<T> adapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) new TypeAdapter<>() {
             @Override
             public void write(JsonWriter out, Object value) throws IOException {
                 delegate.write(out, value);
             }
 
             @Override
             public Object read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
-                JsonElement jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(in);
- 
-                Object value = delegate.fromJsonTree(jsonObject);
+                Object value = delegate.read(in);
                 if (value instanceof Object[]) {
                     Object[] array = (Object[]) value;
                     for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
                         if (array[i] instanceof String) {
                             switch ((String)array[i]) {
                                 case "Infinity":
                                 case "-Infinity":
                                 case "NaN":
                                     array[i] = Double.valueOf((String) array[i]);
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }
                 return value;
             }
         };
 
         return adapter;
     }
 }
 
 private class ValuesObject {
     private final int type;
+    @JsonAdapter(ValuesObjectTypeAdapterFactory.class)
     private final Object[] values;
 
     public ValuesObject(int type, Object[] values) {
         this.type = type;
         this.values = values;
     }
 
     @Override
     public int hashCode() {
         final int prime = 31;
         int result = 1;
         result = prime * result + Arrays.deepHashCode(values);
         result = prime * result + Objects.hash(type);
         return result;
     }
 
     // snip... equals and hashCode
     
 }
```

Comment: Please could you write an example if you have time?

Comment: @doc, I have included the suggested code changes in the answer; hopefully that helps.